# How to use a variable in XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, vbscript

**Not working:**

```vb
Set checkbox = page.FindChildByXPath("//div[@class='dojoxGridContent']//div[@role='presentation']//div//table//tbody//td//img[@onclick='ChangeCheckbox('" + i + "');']")
Set checkbox = page.FindChildByXPath("//div[@class='dojoxGridContent']//div[@role='presentation']//div//table//tbody//td//img[@onclick='ChangeCheckbox(' + i + ');']")
```

Can't seem to get the syntax correct. 
`checkbox` is a Null object after that line is run.

**The following works fine:**

```vb
Set checkbox = page.FindChildByXPath("//div[@class='dojoxGridContent']//div[@role='presentation']//div//table//tbody//td//img[@onclick='ChangeCheckbox(1);']")
```

I want to be able to substitute the `1` with a variable `i` so that I can use different check boxes.

Comment: Can you show your xml?

Comment: `@onclick='ChangeCheckbox(" + i + ");']"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You were wise to make it work with a constant as a sanity check.**  The rest is so much simpler after that success...

Your working example with a constant,

```
"blah blah blah CONSTANT blah blah blah"
```

becomes

```
"blah blah blah " + VARIABLE + " blah blah blah"
```

So, in your specific case:

```
Set checkbox = page.FindChildByXPath("//div[@class='dojoxGridContent']//div[@role='presentation']//div//table//tbody//td//img[@onclick='ChangeCheckbox(" + i + ");']")
```